# Inputs with required prop not being checked after being created with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cakephp

I'm working on a contact form that has an "alternative adress" `<div id='alt'>` with toggleable visibility. It contains a `required <input>`field.  At first I ran into the problem, that after toggling `#alt` twice (thus not displaying it because it's set to `display:none` at the start), the required field would still be checked for a `value`, even though it shouldnt be. This happened because I implemented a jQuery function to replace the "Fill out this field" string, that pops up if a `required` field is left unfilled.

```
$('.submit').click(function () {
            $('input').filter('[required]:visible').each(function () {
                if ($(this).attr('type') == 'text') {
                    if ($(this).val() == '') {
                        this.setCustomValidity("custom text");
                    } else {
                        this.setCustomValidity("");
                    }
                }
            });
            $('')
        });
```

Because of the way handlers are being applied to elements, I was forced to completely remove and re-create the content of the `#alt` div when toggled.

```
$('#open_alt').click(function () {
            $(this).hide();            //hide the "show" button
            $('#close_alt').show();    //show the "hide" button
            $("#alt").fadeToggle();    //show the #alt div
            $(this).next().next().html(blockhtml); //re-create the content of the #alt div
            $('#OrderPhoneAlt').prop('required', 'required'); //this probably isnt necessary, but I wanted to make sure that the required input field in question really has the necessary prop
        });
$('#close_alt').click(function () {
            $(this).hide();             //hide the "hide" button
            $('#open_alt').show();      //show the "show" button
            $("#alt").fadeToggle();     //hide the #alt div
            blockhtml = $(this).next().html(); //store the content of the #alt div
            $(this).next().html(''); //empty the #alt div
        });
```

Now, after toggling the `#alt` div twice, the browser doesnt check my `required <input>` anymore, even though it has the `required`-prop.

This obviously has to do with re-creating the html elements, but is there a way to solve this?

The project is based on CakePHP 1.3 if thats of importance, but I dont think so.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing

```
$('#OrderPhoneAlt').prop('required', 'required');
```

To

```
$('#OrderPhoneAlt').prop('required', true);
```

If is not working please post your html output, and blockhtml content

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery.on() to check dynamic elements.

http://api.jquery.com/on/